# How to build a centralized error handling in node js express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

I am trying to work on error handling in node js application. Can anyone help me how to build centralized error handling without using try and catch block in each api. I am little bit confused on how to do this. Someone please help me.

I have tried creating in middleware error function.

Comment: You can wrap up your controller in another function that contains a try-catch block, so you don't need to write a try-catch block every time in the controller.

Comment: Or you can use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-errors) library to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently need to do error handling. So, went through so many resources and finally came up with this. We will be creating a `custom Error class` and `ErrorHandler middleware`. Custom Error class is used to dynamically send other details like statusCode along with errMsg. And, the middleware is used to centrally handle all the error at once which basically consoles the complete error and send a error response.

1. Create a custom `Err`

   ```
   class Err extends Error {
      statusCode = 500;
      name = "InternalError";
      err = "Error";

      constructor(message, options = {}) {
        super(message);

        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(options)) {
           this[key] = value;
        }
      }
   }
   ```

The Err class accepts the following unlike the in-built Error class which only accepts `message`.

- `message`: Whatever you want to show to client
- `options`: It can include addtional information related to the error like

  - `err` (the actual error)
  - `name` (custom/actual name of error)
  - `statusCode` (like 400, 404, etc)

2. Create a middleware `ErrorHandler`

   ```
   const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
      console.error(err);

      let errStatus = err.statusCode || 500; 
      let errMsg = err.message;

      //handling some basic mongodb error
      if(err.name === 'CastError') {
        errMsg = `Resource not found. Invalid: ${err.path}`;
        errStatus = 400;
      } else if(err.name === 'ValidationError') {
        errMsg = `Invalid input entered: ${Object.values(err.errors).map(e => e.message)}`;
        errStatus = 400;
      } else if(err.code === 11000) {
        errMsg = `Duplicate ${Object.keys(err.keyValues)} entered`;
        errStatus = 403;
      }
      //you can handle many more such in-built or basic errors like related to jwt, etc

      return res.status(errStatus).json({
        success: false,
        status: errStatus,
        message: errMsg,
        stack: process.env.ENV === 'DEV' ? err.stack : {}
      })
   }
   ```

Now, the error handling is just easy-peasy.

- Whenever we want to throw an custom error we can do like

  ```
   const err = throw new Err("Leaderboard not exist for this quiz", {
      err: "RedisError", 
      name: "EmptySetError", 
      statusCode: 422
   });
  ```

  [*Note: It is not required to send all the options, if you want you can only send statusCode.*]
- Or if we are catching an error from try...catch block

  ```
   try {
     //do your work like await call
   } catch (err) {

   }
  ```

And we can modify the controller like

```
const ctrl = (req, res, next) => {
   //err is either custom or we are catching from try...catch
   next(err);
}
```

We will add this middleware at the last of the all routes in your `index.js` file.

```
app.routes....
app.use(ErrorHandler);
```

At last, few tips for better error handling:

1. Friend `throw`, `try`, `catch` with async/await
2. Log errors to the server which will be handled by middleware.
3. Throw your own custom errors using `Err` class
4. Centrally handling errors will make it easy to debug and read code.
5. Provide proper error codes.